# How to remove an object from an array, with a function within itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove the players[0] by using a function from within itself. This example was my first idea but it didn't work, please help me.

```
    // Stores the players
    var players = [];

    // Prototype of a new player
    var newPlayer = {
      hp: 100,
      xCord: 100,
      yCord: 100,

      // My try of removing player from inside itself
      removePlayer: function(){
          players.splice(0, 1);
      }
    }

    // Push the newPlayer prototype into the players array
    players.push(newPlayer);

    // Try to remove the player
    players[0].removePlayer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `0`, try `.indexOf(this)` in the remove function. This will remove an element at any position:

```js
var players = [];

var newPlayer = {
  hp: 100,
  xCord: 100,
  yCord: 100,

  removePlayer: function() {
    players.splice(players.indexOf(this), 1);
  }
}

players.push("test");

players.push(newPlayer);

players.push("something");

console.log(players);

players[1].removePlayer();

console.log(players);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you mean by

> didn't work

If you put `console.log(players);` after your code, you will find the players Array is empty, so your code works.